# Switzerland - IEC vs UL vs VDE vs CSA ratings

Tags: maximum-ratings, certification

I'm currently looking for a new connector for a PCB embedded in a household device with ABS housing (UL94 V-0 rated).
The connectors must withstand a permanent voltage of 400 VAC (+/- 10%). They have 5 terminals with 3 phases, 1 neutral and 1 protective earth.

By looking at the different datasheets, I don't understand the following:

- There are different voltages specified for each category (I/1, II/2, III/3). If I'm right, household devices like mine are in category II/2. Is it right?
- For now, I'm using the connector 691352710005 from Würth Electronik but it's rated for 300 VAC (working voltage). So I'm afraid it can cause us troubles in the future. The connector was chosen by the external company which designed the actual PCB but I want to change it. Or is it safe to use it anyway?
- But most important thing, the datasheets sometimes specify different ratings coming from either different norms like IEC/UL or different certifications/testing institutes like UL/VDE/CSA. For the same connector, the rating can go from 250 to 630 VAC. So, as the product will be used in Switzerland, which rating from which certification institute/norms are to be taken into consideration? It looks weird to me that the same piece of hardware can be ok up to 630 VAC under a norm but only ok up to 230 VAC under another one. It's the same connector...

Comment: Products are designed for the voltage at which they will be used, not the highest voltage on the grid. Embedded PCBs are designed for voltages used on the PCB, not necessarily the maximum voltage in the product. Household devices are usually designed for single-phase, 240 volts or less. UL is for USA or Canada and CSA is for Canada or USA. Each agency can label for both countries. I am voting to close the question as unclear.

Comment: What sort of household device needs 3 phase power?

Comment: @JackB It's a device to monitor current consumption of washing machines. Such machines have 3 phases.

Comment: Do you have examples of household washing machines on three phases? Do they have a CEE FORM plug? Since all washers here limit to 2kW, the maximum of a schuko.

Comment: @Jeroen3 I don't have a precise model in mind but almost all high-end Swiss washing machine have 3 phases (you can have a look to Schulthess or V-Zug machines for example). They are designed to be used in semi-public environment (shared laundry rooms in apartment blocks). These machines are usually bought by owners of buildings, comes only with a 5-wires cable and a certified electrician install them.

Comment: @Carton_ - Hi, I appreciate that you wanted to update/clarify the question with an edit. However that edit removed the specific question about a connector which was actually answered. Changing a question in a way that invalidates existing answers is generally not allowed, so I have reverted (rolled-back) that edit. Perhaps consider asking a new question, if you want this one to be different? || Please let me know in a comment that you have seen this, and I can remove my comment here. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited the question again and tried to took your remarks into account

Answer (score 2):

It is not.

The working voltage rating is 300V due to the pins being only 5 mm apart on the pcb. That gives you only 2 mm of distance between copper.

The 7.5/7.62mm pitch variant should be fine, or you can skip a pin between 400V terminals.   However, that will add two more pins in width.

Comment: So the whole PCB design of the AC part is wrong... There are less than 2mm distance between copper traces.

Comment: The exception is when you have milled slots between them with insulators or potting. But sub 2 mm milling is expensive.